# Atlassian TreeMap - How to control the values of the "parents"?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, treemap, amcharts4

I try to control the value of the "parents" regardless of the "children"
In TreeMap. Right now what happens when children have value. The "parent" receives as a value the entire amount of children.
Even when I give the parent value. He does not refer to it.
my question is:
**How do I give a parent a new value with which you can make a parent arrangement independent of children?**

JsonInput:

```
const jsonData =[{
  "name": "First",
  "value": 20000, //Parent value
  "children": [
    { "name": "A1", "value": 100 }, //children value
    { "name": "A2", "value": 60 }, //children value
    { "name": "A3", "value": 30 } //children value
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Second",
  "value": 140000, //Parent value
  "children": [
    { "name": "B1", "value": 135 }, //children value
    { "name": "B2", "value": 98 }, //children value
    { "name": "B3", "value": 56 } //children value
  ]
}]
```

Code:

```
const level1 = chart.seriesTemplates.create("0");
let level1_column = level1.columns.template;
const level1_bullet = level1.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());

level1_bullet.label.text =  "{value}";  //The value is the sum of the values of all his children.


const level2 = chart.seriesTemplates.create("1");
let level2_column = level2.columns.template;
const level2_bullet = level2.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());

level2_bullet.label.text =  "{value}";  //The value is of the child.
```

Comment: I need the parent to sort by "his value field" and not by "the sum of all the children of that parent"